# JSON endpoint in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to return straight text in a page using meteor? Say someone requested domain.com/get/that-thing, and I just wanted to return the string "52", so that the requester knows that-thing has "52" of something. To my understanding, this is not possible in Meteor because the headers and such are always included.

2 hacks that would work:
Write to a file named "that-thing" in anticipation that "that-thing" might be called. This doesn't work in the general case.
Put a reverse proxy that redirects some of the requests to a non-meteor backend.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router supports this; check out the server side routing: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router

Comment: **meteor-router** is *officially* ***discontinued***. the meteor-router GitHub repo points users to https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router which *does not support JSON*. :-( writing a custom solution. Let me know if you want me to share)

Answer (score 14):

I had to solve this today and using **Iron-Router** server-side-routing: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#server-side-routing

Simple example:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('api', {
    path: '/api',
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
      var json = Collection.find().fetch(); // what ever data you want to return
      this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      this.response.end(JSON.stringify(json));
  }
});
});
```

This will return a valid JSON "page" which you can then use how ever you want.

Thanks to @Akshat for answering: [Meteor Iron-Router Without Layout Template or JSON View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915857/meteor-iron-router-without-layout-template-or-json-view/22916375#22916375)