# Meteor Iron-Router Without Layout Template or JSON View

Tags: json, meteor, iron-router

Using Meteor Iron-Router how can I *either* render data as JSON or simply display it "raw" (without a layout template)

Essentially I want to be able to do something like:

```
this.route('rawdata', {
  path: '/raw/:collection',
  layoutTemplate: 'nolayout',
  template: 'raw'
})
```

where **/raw/posts** would display the raw json of Posts (the collection).

Thanks!

**Notes**:

I'm aware of [JSON endpoint in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601218/json-endpoint-in-meteor)
But meteor-router is discontinued and Iron-Router does not appear to have a JSON-end-point feature.

I also had a look at https://atmospherejs.com/package/collection-api but it does not suit my needs because I need the ability to select a subset of the fields of the collection/record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a raw layout template

```
<template name="direct_layout">
    {{> yield}}
</template>
```

Then use that as your layoutTemplate to directly use your template.

```
this.route('rawdata', {
    path: '/raw/:collection',
    layoutTemplate: 'direct_layout',
    template: 'raw'
});
```

I'm not sure whether you're using this as a placeholder for your actual code. If you intend to render data using JSON or actual raw text. You might want to consider using server-side routes. You should do something like this instead:

Note that this is server side code, unlike the above which runs on the client side:

```
this.route('serverRoute', {
  where: 'server',
  path: '/your-route',
  action: function() {
    var data = {this_is:'a json object'}


    this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    this.response.end(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

Have a look at Server side rendering on Iron-Router: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#server-side-routing

Comment: Thanks for the more complete answer Akshat.

Comment: @nelsonic This answer should work for you. The reststop2 package basically does exactly this - it came out before iron-router supported server-side routes. If you need more flexibility over response type, authentication, routing, parameters, etc. take a look at reststop2.

http://github.differential.io/reststop2/

Comment: How do you call a server side route? Is it localhost:3000/raw/:collection ?

Comment: @Nate Just like how you've defined it for `path` and use `this.params.collection`

Comment: I am trying to get your server side code to work, which I am able to do. However I don't understand how I would pass data into the action function. If I try to define `data=Messages.findOne()` it returns that messages is not defined. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nate it doesn't look like this code is the one giving the issues, if `Messages` is undefined you might have to structure your app so that where you defined it `Messages = new Meteor.Coll...` runs before this bit of code does. In essence this undefined error is because it can't find the definition for your Messages collection

Answer (score 2):

See: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/114

(Note the comment amending the content type.)