# How to generate XML files in Meteor using Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I need to generate a simple XML file to call with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say).

Currently, I am trying to output this at a particular route:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">Hello, world!</Say>
</Response>
```

I plan on making it dynamic later and hence, cannot place it with the other asset files.

In my routes file, I am not sure what to do with this. I cannot place this in a template because that gives an error for obvious reasons.

```
// Twilio voice call TwiML
Router.route('/twilio/my_twiml.xml', {
    // ??
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22916375/804503) answer, I was able to get this to work by:

```
Router.route('/twilio/my_twiml.xml', {
  where: 'server',
  action: function() {

    var xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    xmlData += "<Response>";
    xmlData += "<Say voice=\"woman\" language=\"en\">Hello!</Say>";
    xmlData += "</Response>";

    this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'});
    this.response.end(xmlData);
  }
});
```

Note that this is a server-side route.